# View a colorful PDF/PS without colors, as it would look like when printed

Tags: pdf, postscript, evince

I am working on an article with colorful drawings, but because it will be printed on black-and-white printers, I want to make sure it looks good without colors.

I have Ubuntu and currently use Evince to view the paper (in Postscript or PDF format). Is there a way to tell Evince to show me the paper as it would look like when printed on a black-and-white printer?

Alternatively, is there a different PS/PDF viewer that can do this?

Comment: Another place to look would be in the Accessibility settings (although I am not sufficiently familiar with Ubuntu to confirm that it would work).

Answer (score 1):

GIMP can import PDFs and desaturate them to grayscale.  See [the GIMP docs](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-desaturate.html).  A bit clunky, but it would work.